# How can I resend an application on Careers?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, jobs

I applied for a job a year ago, and things didn't pan out then and I didn't hear back.

I'd like to resubmit my application as the job has been reposted and my skillset has become broader, but Careers doesn't let me send an application again, it just says "You applied for this position on {date last year}.  Good luck!" with no "apply now" button.

In my Messages section, I can view the application but there's no way to withdraw the application or anything, and I can't even post a comment to it as I have a message saying "You must wait until the employer responds to your application."  It's been a year; I don't think they are going to respond to the old application after so long, but I'm left with no way to resubmit my information to them.

It seems counter-intuitive and unlike other job sites that you basically get only one chance to apply to a job, even if said job gets reposted at a later date.  There should either be a way to resubmit an application, withdraw an application, or the system should allow reapplying after some arbitrary amount of time has passed so you aren't left seeing a job that you're a good fit for this time around but with no way to apply for it since you already applied once before.

Answer (score 5):

Right now there's no way to resubmit an application. This is probably an oversight on our part considering a job listing can be re-posted years later. <s>I'll add this our ever growing feature request Trello board</s>.

Nevermind, the devs are already looking into how to fix it as we speak.

Comment: Awesome, great to know!

Comment: Should be good to go later today.

Comment: Based on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267740/why-cant-i-apply-for-the-same-position-even-after-a-year), this is still not possible to resend an application. Can you please look into it?