# Why can't I apply for the same position even after a year

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, jobs

for example, I keep getting:

> You applied for this position on Sep 11. Good Luck!

even though this was last year.

Comment: Weird, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232398/how-can-i-resend-an-application-on-careers), you should be able to do that

Answer (score 2):

Our record of job applications shows that you didn't apply for any jobs on 2014-09-11. You did however [apply for a job](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/438211/messages/#!/sent/applications/1043755) on 2015-09-11 and that job didn't exist last year so I'm pretty certain that we're doing the right thing here.

Drop us an email at careers@stackoverflow.com with further details if you think this is still a bug!

**UPDATE**

We only allow re-applying to a job after 6 months have passed from the last application. That's clearly the case here and I just impersonated your account to verify that you can still apply to the job you mention in comments; the apply button is there and functional, although we still show the last time you applied which I think is where the confusion comes in.

When a job is re-posted it isn't cloned; the same database record is used and we simply update the job's history (it's actually a bit more involved than that but that's the TL;DR). Applications for that job are therefore still associated with it. We think that's the best solution because most employers don't want repeat applications from a candidate within the same 6 month period even if the job was re-posted.

So, in summary, you can re-apply to any job after 6 months have passed. Any time the 'Apply' button is present means you can apply. Message at the top of the view is simply for information in that case.

Comment: I was just giving that exact date as an example of the message, but you can check an application of mine on 2015-01-19, even though the job post is re-posted multiple times (4 days a go for example). I guess the re-posting implementation didn't just duplicate the post with a newer date, but it clones the applications too somehow.

Comment: @m7moud updated the answer to address you questions.

Comment: So isn't this [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeh, you're right. Lack of sleep after the meet-up :p

Comment: All good! Glad to hear you're back safely, and that now bugs would start getting fixed... :D

Comment: @DeanWard the apply button is present, and you are right, I just didn't know that 6 months rule before, so I guess I have checked a job post before this 6 months from my last application. Thank you.